# How to use a for loop for assigning a value in an array?

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to draw a tic tac toe board by using a for loop in javascript to create it. But it wasn't drawing it at all. I know that the two files are linked because I tried it out before. But this isn't working. Anyone know an answer.

Javascript

```js
var array = [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "];
for(i = 0;i < 8;i++){
 array[i] = "| |";
 document.getElementById(board).innerHTMl = "|   |"];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="body">
<div><h1 id="middle">Tic Tac Toe</h1></div>
<p id="board"></p>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you setting the `innerHTML` repeatedly to the same thing? Why does that line need to be in the loop?

Comment: Start off by viewing your console for syntax errors.

Comment: how do you view your console?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already used this successfully before (as mentioned in OP, share a fiddle otherwise), there are three typos in your code

1) This line has an extra square bracket at the end

```
document.getElementById(board).innerHTMl = "|   |"];
                                                  ^
```

should be

```
 document.getElementById(board).innerHTMl = "|   |";
```

2) `broad` is not a variable, it should be a string literal

```
document.getElementById('board').innerHTMl = "|   |";
                        ^     ^
```

3) `innerHTMl` should be `innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById('board').innerHTML = "|   |";
                                 --------^
```

Comment: How about `innerHTMl` ?

Answer (score -1):

```js
var array = [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "];
for(i = 0;i < 8;i++){
 array[i] = "| |";
 $('#board').append("| | ");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="body">
<div><h1 id="middle">Tic Tac Toe</h1></div>
<p id="board"></p>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```